# How to get reliable memory info on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, memory-management

I am currently working on an app that runs on iOS and Android. The core of the app is written in C++ and allocates over time more and more memory. The thing is I want at the same time to be able to use as much memory as possible and ensure the stability of the app.

Of course, to do that I would need to know how much memory I can still use. This way, if I see after a while that I am going to need more than it is available, I could stop allocating instead of getting killed by the OS or crashing.

The problem is, after reading and trying different solutions, my feeling is the information that you dynamically get is not reliable enough. For instance, on iOS:

```
[NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory
```

This is one of the typical examples / answers I have read that seems not to be reliable. It seems that you cannot get enough information dynamically to make sure that you still have enough memory, because the OS will at some point kill your app if it uses too much memory and sends warnings before. But it also can kill other apps in between, so stopping when I receive the first one seems not to be an optimal solution.

After reading a lot of posts, I am a bit confused on the topic. Is there a way to know dynamically and reliably how much memory is left for my app on iOS/Android ? Or memory management from these OS is too unpredictable for that ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: In android and iOS there are listeners for memory warning, maybe a callback to your C++ code will be useful. iOS=> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html Android=>https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: Thank you Sulfkain. The only problem with these callback is that they are unpredictable in the sense that you cannot know how much memory you still can use when you receive one. I could stop when I receive the first one, but I am trying here to get as much memory as I can.

Comment: Read on android the article I said, search for "Check how much memory you should use" as title. There explain how to get more ram and get the memory available, maybe it's usefull. On iOS maybe there is something similar

Comment: Ok, so it seems that on Android, `OutOfMemoryError` can be used, but I still need to check out what's its behaviour. However on iOS there are no real equivalent ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, you're prohibited by the operating system from ever using up all the physical memory on the device; what's more, the requirements of the operating system and the other apps running on it mean that the amount of memory your app can comfortably use will vary over time.

Therefore asking how much memory you have left to use isn't really sensible. You should design your app to use as little memory as possible, and then optimize until you use less than that.

- Be aggressive about caching things out to disk.
- Listen to the OS-provided notifications that your memory is under pressure.
- Design your app in such a way that you can restore its last UI state from fresh launch: app launches and task switches are presented to the user the same way, and they won't and shouldn't need to know the difference.

If you do use more and more memory, the OS will try and terminate other apps to make room for yours. That means, bye bye Facebook, bye bye Twitter, bye bye Mail, bye bye Contacts. Your users *will* notice, and they *will* choose to launch your app less often, or review it less favorably, as a result.

Comment: Your points are completely valid, and I actually agree with you, especially from the user's perspective. In my case, the problem is I do not want to have any fixed boundaries for my app. Apple even provides the corresponding tip: **"Avoid unbounded problem sets."**

Comment: Heh, maybe try not running on a computer that runs on a battery and fits in your pocket :) Tho seriously, when I for fun wanted to see how much was *really* available, I set up a loop to deliberately leak 16k of memory at a time, logging the count so far and any memory pressure events that occurred. That gave me some indication of how the memory pressure system behaved, but I wouldn't want to rely on it across OS versions, devices, or specific user's environments at a given point in time.

Comment: Hehe ;-) That's interesting, I am trying to do exactly that at the moment. Did you get any useful information out of it ? Any particular event / callback that happens just before the OS kills the app ?

Comment: No, just a standard `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`.